# Using Local Routing Tool in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst

When I create a model in ArcGIS ModelBuilder using the Network Analyst Tools, I am able to create Locations and make the Route Layer and Solve.  However, I need to be able to add barriers as well as locations, before solving for the Route.

Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Comment: The thing that I'm having trouble with now (with the new model that includes barriers) is that when I run the model, then when I click on locations, I don't know if the process sees the locations as barriers or stops. I get error messages when it runs. How can I indicate which I am clicking on when it runs? Thanks.

Comment: See the screen shot above? The location you're adding is set as a Barrier. The point you provide into each feature set already has its behavior defined.  - the easiest way to test this in Desktop is to run it with 2 stops ( each on the same line, with 1 full street inbetween), then add the barrier on the same street inbetween the 2 intersections. The round should move around the barrier instead of straight line

Comment: OK, thanks.  I was able to resolve this and also to integrate the addition of barriers into my C# code.  Now I just need to be able to indicate somewhere in the model, that the Barriers input parameter is optional, because I can't use the existing gpk that I created from the model unless I input barriers as well as Stops. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: I guess I can't change this input parameter to "optional".  I'll have to take another look at my model to see if there is a way around this.

Answer (score 2):

Barriers (Point, Line and Polygons Barriers) can be created/per-loaded before the solving to route.

> Barriers can be added into barrier classes via the Create Network
> Location ToolCreate Network Location Tool on the Network Analyst
> toolbar, the Load Locations dialog box, or the Add Locations
> geoprocessing tool. When barriers are created, loaded, or added, they
> affect only the items checked on the Network Locations tab of the
> network analysis layer's Layer Properties dialog box. This is true
> even when a barrier intersects layers that are unchecked on the
> Network Locations tab

**Loading Point Barriers**

When a point barrier is loaded or created, **it snaps to the nearest network edge or junction within a search tolerance.** The position of the barrier on the network is specified by the network location fields (`SourceID, SourceOID, SideOfEdge, and PosAlong`). When a restriction point barrier is on an edge, you can opt to restrict travel across the point barrier only, or restrict the edge entirely. A scaled cost point barrier adds a cost whenever it is crossed.

Line and Polygon Barriers also supported

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004700000056000000

#### Edit to add information

This screen shot might help clear it up - just add a new location of "barrier" type to your network analyst layer. In the screen shot, all 3 (start/end/barriers) are feature sets for the user to provide input with.

[image]